# Does Prospective Search support ndb.model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

A colleague is getting

> DocumentTypeError: Document type is not supported.

when calling `Subscribe` using an ndb document type, on the dev appserver.
Are *ndb* and *Prospective Search* compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ndb and Prospective search are compatible but you need to use prospective_search for ndb:

`from google.appengine.ext.ndb import prospective_search`

Regarding the error, from the source:

> get_document()  Raises DocumentTypeError: if document class is not recognized.

http://appengine-ndb-experiment.googlecode.com/hg/ndb/prospective_search.py